# Real time search + pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I currently use Laravel's pagination and whenever I need a search feature I simply add a search box that when submitted, saves the value in a session key in the backend and then it refreshes the page with the filtered query.

Now I want to change it to be real time search so that the page won't refresh.

Should I then use only JS for that without Laravel's pagination, or combine the two? i.e. have an identical method in the controller for API calls (via fetch/ajax), where one returns the view, and one returns the paginated data as JSON:

```
public function my_page(Request $request)
{
    // some more stuff to gather

    return view('user.index', [
    'pagination_data' => DB::table('some_table')->paginate(15)
    'some_other_data' => $some_other_data
    ]);
}
```

And an api endpoint for that view:

```
public function my_page_pagination_api(Request $request)
 {
    return response()->json([
    'pagination_data' => DB::table('some_table')->where('some_column', 'LIKE', $request->input('search')->paginate(15);
    ]);
}
```

Then I call that endpoint via JS and update the HTML in real time, instead of refreshing the page (Both the table and the `->links()`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your my_page_pagination_api as follows

```
    public function my_page_pagination_api(Request $request)
    {

    $pagination_data = DB::table('some_table')
    ->where('some_column', 'LIKE', $request->input('search')->paginate(15);

    // Return the paginated data as JSON response
    return response()->json([
        'pagination_table' => view('partials.table', ['pagination_data' => $pagination_data])->render(),
        'pagination_links' => $pagination_data->links()->render(),
    ]);
    }
```

And for updating the table content

```
function updateContent(data) {
        $('#tableContainer').html(data.pagination_table); // Update the table data
        $('#paginationContainer').html(data.pagination_links); // Update the pagination links
    }
```

For the frontend you may use the simple on change or on input trigger to perform search with some validations like character counts or empty spaces.